# ObjectMapper's readValue method giving MismatchedInputException

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm using the objectMapper to first serialise and deserialise an object.
I'm serialising the object here:

```
byte[] data = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(service.getServiceInfo());
client.create().withMode(CreateMode.EPHEMERAL).forPath(service.getLeaderPath(), data);
```

The `getServiceInfo` is of type: `ServiceInfo.class`
Here is how I'm trying to deserialise the data:

```
byte[] data = client.getData().forPath(service.getLeaderPath());
T serviceInfo = objectMapper.readValue(data, typeServiceInfo);
```

Here `T` is of type `ServiceInfo.class` and typeServiceInfo is it's class variable `Class<T>`

This is the ServiceInfo.class:

```
@Data
public class ServiceInfo {
  private String name;

  public ServiceInfo(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Now when I run my code, I obtain a `MismatchedInputException`
This is the error trace I obtained:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.nutanix.categories.beans.curator.ServiceInfo` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"name":"2816c308-5277-4b23-bdd6-64d6f3513e16"}"; line: 1, column: 2]

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1429)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1059)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3266)
    at com.nutanix.categories.curators.ServiceLeaderLatch.start(ServiceLeaderLatch.java:74)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is deeply appreciated.

*PS: Please mention if I have to submit additional information regarding my query in the comments*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve it:

1. Modify the ServiceInfo bean itself and remove the constructor. Although, it will require you to update all it's declarations.

   ```
    @Data
    public class ServiceInfo {
        private String name;
    }
   ```
2. Or, add `@JsonCreator` annotation to the bean

   ```
    @Data
    public class ServiceInfo {
        private String name;

        @JsonCreator
        public ServiceInfo(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
             this.name = name;
        }
    }
   ```

If you don't like `@JsonProperty` annotation, you can customize `ObjectMapper`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-paranamer</artifactId>
        <version>${some-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then register the module:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModules(new ParanamerModule());
```

Comment: I also found that adding a default constructor with call to super() also works.

Comment: added one more way

Answer (score 2):

Another option is leave everything as it is and add a default constructor

```
    @Data
    public class ServiceInfo {
      private String name;
      
      public ServiceInfo() {
      }

      public ServiceInfo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }
    }
```